Training models for production
Not entirely sure which workflow is considered correct.
Say for both workflows, I have 10 splits for my test data and perform walk-forward validation during training.
Is it better use the last model in production that was trained on 9 of the splits and validated on the 10th split. Versus, using the hyperparameters that were found previously to retrain a new model on all the available test data. Both workflows will be validated with a holdout set.
My results show that the first approach is better but something is telling me to use all available test data prior to going into production.

How about: throwing away (forgetting) the oldest of the 10 splits,  appending to the 9 remaing splits the most recent (validation period) data and retraining on those 10 periods. I am not saying this is necessarily better, but is what I think "walk forward" methodology is generally understood to mean. And do the same thing going forward.

I think you are referring to walk forward optimization. But similar conundrum can be used there. Train on all available data as 10 splits, during this training all splits are validated. Now do you use the model you have now or retrain it on the best parameters on all 10 splits without validation before giving it current incoming data?

I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to pertain directly enough to QF.
